# Change date format in jquery-ui calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

At first I showed a calender and when a date is selected it will show on the input field.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="shadow">
                <div id="datepicker"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 pt-2">
            <div class="shadow">
                <input type="text" id="my-input" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my script

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(e) {
            console.log("Selected date: " + e + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
            $("#my-input").val(e)
        }
    });
});
```

I want to change the date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', //Just added this line into my code
            onSelect: function(e) {
                console.log("Selected date: " + e + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
                $("#my-input").val(e)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add the [`dateFormat` option](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

Note that `yy` is [four digits](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate).

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
  onSelect: function(e) {
    console.log("Selected date: " + e + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
    $("#my-input").val(e)
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes I just did that